# How To Make A new Line in PHP that is in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

so the issue I am facing at the moment is the following. I am trying to get the departure board to show up like this [Departure Board 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw1yq.png) This board was done using laravel and I am now trying to do it with PHP and the main issue im running into is when I try to break the line and the end of a string it shows the BR on the board [As Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb20u.png) Below you will find the HTML source code everything that is meant to appear appears but instead of it being on different lines it is still in 1 line

```
(['EIN139 EIDW KBOS<br>EIN13T EIDW KBOS<br>EIN1GE EIDW CYYZ<br>RYR1923 EIDW 
EPKK<br>RYR35CW EIDW EGKK<br>RYR67C EIDW EGBB<br>RYR681C EIDW EGBB<br>RYR6CM 
EIDW EHAM<br>RYR73WK EIDW EGGW<br>RYR81SU EIDW LEGE<br>RYR87CJ EIDW 
EGBB<br>'])
```

I have tried Substituting the "'br'" for "\n"; and "\n"; but still without luck.

```
var board = new DepartureBoard (document.getElementById ('test'), { 
rowCount: 10, letterCount: 20 }); 
board.setValue (['<?php foreach ($data as $info) {
if (strlen($info->callsign) > 6) {
    echo $info->callsign.' ';
    echo $info->origin.' ';
    echo $info->destination."<br>";
} elseif (strlen($info->callsign) < 6) {
    echo $info->callsign.'  ';
    echo $info->origin.' ';
    echo $info->destination."<br>";
} else {
    echo $info->callsign.' ';
    echo $info->origin.' ';
    echo $info->destination."<br>";
}
}?>']);
```

Is there something that I've missed or?

```
      @foreach ($data as $info)
      '{{$info->callsign}} {{$info->origin}} {{$info->destination}}',
      @endforeach
```

the code in laravel which is so less complicated than above. I don't see why the laravel code breaks the string automatically and the code above doesn't
Thanks

Comment: what happens if you use \n IT is also not clear to me how you actually display the data. Besides, if it is so easy with the Templating language (hint, pure PHP would be even simpler) why not do that?

Comment: try "\r\n" and wrap your string between "" instead of ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your laravel version you are adding multiple array elements, in your native php version you are putting everything into the same array element.

This:

```
@foreach ($data as $info)
  '{{$info->callsign}} {{$info->origin}} {{$info->destination}}',
@endforeach
```

Is going to produce something like

```
'BRKS SKDFK SDFSDF', 'SDFKE SDFSk SDFSDF', 'SDFDSF EGFAS SDFSE'
```

While your other version is going to produce this

```
'BRKS SKDFK SDFSDF SDFKE SDFSk SDFSDF SDFDSF EGFAS SDFSE'
```

Change your code around so that you are splitting up your lines into different array elements.

```
board.setValue ([<?php foreach ($data as $info) {
echo "'";
 // echo actual line data here
echo "',";
?>]);
```

Notice the single quotes are echoed in each iteration. Note that this is not the optimal way to do it, as you will more than likely end up with a trailing comma. You could possibly use php's array_map to create each line and then json_encode the result, and echo it into the spot needed.

```
$lineFunction = function($info) {
  $line = "";
  if (strlen($info->callsign) > 6) {
      $line .= $info->callsign.' '.
               $info->origin.' '.
               $info->destination;
  } elseif (strlen($info->callsign) < 6) {
      $line .= $info->callsign.'  '.
               $info->origin.' '.
               $info->destination;
  } else {
      $line .= $info->callsign.' '.
               $info->origin.' '.
               $info->destination;
  }
  return $line;
};

$lines = array_map($lineFunction, $data);
?>
board.setValue (<?php echo json_encode($lines);?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **PHP_EOL**..

```
var board = new DepartureBoard (document.getElementById ('test'), { 
rowCount: 10, letterCount: 20 }); 
board.setValue (['<?php foreach ($data as $info) {
if (strlen($info->callsign) > 6) {
    echo $info->callsign.' ';
    echo $info->origin.' ';
    echo $info->destination.PHP_EOL;
} elseif (strlen($info->callsign) < 6) {
    echo $info->callsign.'  ';
    echo $info->origin.' ';
    echo $info->destination.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo $info->callsign.' ';
    echo $info->origin.' ';
    echo $info->destination.PHP_EOL;
}
}?>']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is a textarea or something similar.
To brake lines inside such elements you need to use `\n` and not html.

Besides, if templating language makes it easy (and pure PHP would be even more easy) why not use that?

Comment: I have included \n in the code replacing "<br>" but it then run into the issue the board then disappears https://imgur.com/2b2n9bf with error outputs

Answer (score 0):

> **Laravel Blade Engine**

Use `{!! '<br>' !!}` instead of `{{ '<br>' }}`.

Laravel automatically escapes characters inside the regular echo braces `{{}}`.

**Beware**: This can be an entry point for XSS.